# Where to find the "Libraries" folder (Netbeans JAR)

Tags: java

I want to add an external library but I cannot find the folder to put it in.

In the youtube videos I've seen, they always put the library JAR to a folder called "Libraries" but I cannot find that:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have a maven project. In this case go to the folder `Project Files` and add the desired dependency in your `pom.xml` file.

Comment: Find the appropriate maven package and right click *Dependenies* *add*. Then you can copy and paste the details. Usually if you search the shortest package in the artifact in a search engine to find the appropriate package but verify the classes you are looking for are present. You can do this by using 7z or any zip tool to browse through the jar file content as if it's a zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by others, your project is a Maven project. In order to add dependencies to a maven project you can either add entries to your pom.xml manually by right clicking your project and clicking "Open POM"

[image]

or automatically by right clicking the "Dependencies" folder and clicking "Add Dependency".
[image]

If using the former, you can find dependencies at https://mvnrepository.com/

If you don't want to use Maven, I would suggest creating your project with ANT instead, which will give you the expected "Libraries" option you are looking for. If you go this way, you add libraries to your project in the "Project properties" (right click project, then "properties"). Make sure you add your libraries to the "Classpath".

[image]

[image]

Comment: woah thanks dude, that's fixed me, thanks a lot, damn I've been searching for almost 1 week,

Comment: @DragonCode Glad to hear it! Feel free to mark this as the accepted answer if it helped you!